# Jhipster-Get profile file to configMAP

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, jhipster, google-kubernetes-engine

I want my profile file to `configmap`, I don't need to compile application if the user of the database has been changed.

Is it possible to push the file below in `configmap` to `kubernetes`?

```
WORHOME/src/main/resources/config/application-prod.yml
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem. If you want to put your `profile` into the `configmap` you can do something like this: `kubectl create configmap --dry-run somename --from-file=./profile --output yaml | tee profile.yaml` and than use it.

Comment: yeah i now but i want to this profile from configmap directly when i apply my deployment. i use jhipster and i dont know if i use configmap to volume